# Trying to extract a number from a plist with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I'll try and make this question short.  Basically, I am working on a shell script, and I have a .plist file containing an integer value that I am trying to "extract" and put into a variable in my shell script.

I'm able to refine the contents of the .plist file to a few lines, but I am still getting a bunch of characters I don't need.

I am delcaring / running the following command in my shell script, and it is giving me the following results.

```
  file_refine=`grep -C 2 CFBundleVersion $file | grep '[0-9]\{3\}'`
```

**Output**

```
  <string>645</string>
```

I just need the numeral digits not the string tags, but I can't seem to figure that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
file_refine=$(grep -C 2 CFBundleVersion $file | grep -o '[0-9]\{3\}')
```

the -o option from grep man page:

```
 -o, --only-matching
              Print  only  the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with
              each such part on a separate output line.
```

Comment: that did the trick, i'll give you credit for the answer once the three minutes is up if i dont forget (-.-)